# Does the Facebook C# SDK support async/await on Windows Phone 7.5?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, async-await

So I'm writing a windows phone 7.5 app.

I used nuget to get version 6.0.10.0 of the Facebook C# SDK.

From what I've read online it appears that I should be able to do the following...

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic r = await fb.GetTaskAsync("4");
```

However, I don't see **GetTaskAsync** as a method of FacebookClient. I just get the usual **GetAsync** method.

Does async/await not work using the Facebook C# SDK on Windows Phone 7.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

http://csharpsdk.org/docs/known-issues

> You cannot use TPL on Windows Phone and as such the Facebook C# SDK
>   does not contain TPL dependant methods in the Windows Phone build.

Longer answer:

The source is on github, so we can look into more specifically why the method doesn't show up.

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/tree/master/Source/Facebook

The csproj files listed show only a target of WP7 (not WP75 or WP8), and as such, doesn't appear that it could use the TPL.

The *TaskAsync methods are implemented in the partial class at FacebookClient.Async.Tasks.cs, and as such, it's not supported in the WP7 build since that source file isn't included in the csproj.

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/blob/master/Source/Facebook/FacebookClient.Async.Tasks.cs

That said, if you're willing to make your own build of the facebook SDK, you might be able to just install the [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PortableTPL) for the [PortableTPL](http://portabletpl.codeplex.com/) and then include that partial class in the csproj (don't know, haven't tried it)